# mysql: When exactly the statement "Start binlog_dump to slave_server" logged in to the master error log 

Tags: mysql, logging, replication

Recently, I have observed the below statement in the master server's MySQL error log many number of times.

```
"started bin_log dump to slave server"
```

I would like to know all the possible cases of when exactly this will be logged in the error log.

How connection failure between master and slave will impact this to be logged into the error log.

I suspect personally when we hit "START SLAVE" on the slave server, But it is not as I tested this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the log-bin ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_log-bin ) parameter in my.cnf and whether you have set a different server-id ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options.html#option_mysqld_server-id )for master & slave.

Comment: YES I set the server-ids differently. I didnt understand how enabling log-bin will impact this.

Comment: Binary logging must be enabled on the master in order to perform replication.

Comment: YES ofourse. What I am asking for is when the above statement will be logged. I guess when we start mysql on the master server. anyways thanks setsuna

Comment: You may wish to ask this question on dba.stackexchange.com. People who know the answer congregate there.

Comment: Ollie.... I have asked this there too... What I observed is that many of the questions I am getting people responding here only on stack overflow itslef..... nyways thanks for your advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exact message is this: `Start binlog_dump to slave_server`

In the source code this string is saved in the logfile when this function is called: `mysql_binlog_send`

With a bit of research, I see that just before this function is called, changes the slave state to this: `Requesting binlog dump` and in the MySQL reference manual says that this state is set just when the slave connects with the master.

So, exactly, this message appears when the slave connects with the master.

So it seems that the slave loses connection with the master and then reconnects.

Comment: Thanks george. Its a great answer. I cant test this as I cant create network fluctuations. But from what u said, that method should be called when we stop and start the slave. But this logging is not happenning then. any guess...........

Answer (score 1):

Is this and error or not?  I suspect "started bin_log dump to slave server" is not the entire log line if it is an error. Please add an actual snippet from the log in question of the repeating notice.

If replication looks like its working fine, this isn't an error.  Non- errors such as servers start and stopping and slave connection status get logged to the MySQL error log.  You can override the default logging levels to lower how much and what gets logged:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-slave.html

Look at the --log-warnings configuration option

I suspect this occurs when you change a slave to a master or when a slave server restarts and try's to reestablish a connection.

Comment: Hi Ray, This is error only. But i didnt see an error code for this error provided along and I have tesed that it is not being written when we restart a slave. This is even not a case when we change the slave to master. Thanks  for your update....

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same condition like that

```
160615 15:40:25 [Note] Start binlog_dump to slave_server(1401), pos(mysql-bin.000020, 219311193)
160622 15:56:58 [Note] Start binlog_dump to slave_server(1401), pos(mysql-bin.000046, 350644600)
```

when i stop the slave, and start slave again ,the master's  mysql error logs would print the note log.

This is nothing to be care. It just means that the slave server (server id is 1401) is begin to connect the master.

Need to be noted that if your masters' mysql error log prints the note log frequently. you will check :

1. whether the network is stable
2. if the master have one more slaves ,check the slaves whether have the same server-id.

that's all.